# Add Dublin Core RDFa markup for better metadata in SO questions

Tags: feature-request, copyright, semantics, metadata

Short version: It would be great if SO added Dublin Core RDFa markup indicating author, title, date, and other metadata for questions and answers.  This would make them easier to cite with tools such as http://greycite.knowledgeblog.org/, among other applications.

SO uses a cc-wiki licence which requires the creator to define how they would want to be acknowledged.  The bottom of every page links to https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/ defining acknowledgement of consisting not only of a link to the question, but also the author names for every question or answer and links to their profiles.

All that additional information is rather redundant once the link has been specified, but very well, it's the required way to cite it, so at least we might try a programmatic solution.  While it would be possible to write a little code to scrape a question URL for this data, it would be much nicer if this data could be provided in a standard format that could be recognized by standard URL citation approaches, such as the Greycite tool linked above.

Comment: Or I guess you could use an `<iframe>`

Comment: If I want to add the citation information to my code comments / documentation, an iframe is hardly a useful way to do that.